# How to purchase zen coins with real money?

Tags: xbox-one, neverwinter

I wish to purchase some zen coins with real money but can't seem to find a way to do so. At the zen market, I can see items costing zen coins being greyed out but there is no way to purchase zen coins in order to buy them.

At the moment, the only way I am aware of to obtain zen coins is to exchange astral diamonds for them ingame.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be just missing something, or you're a bit drunk?

Press <kbd>Start</kbd>, then go across to `Store` and choose `Zen Market`.

When you go to the Zen market, you'll see two tabs at the top left of the screen: `Zen Market` and `Purchase Zen`. You can move between these tabs by pressing <kbd>LB</kbd> and <kbd>RB</kbd>.

Once you're on the `Purchase Zen` screen, you can press <kbd>A</kbd> to buy the currently selected amount.

You'd think it'd be easier to give them your hard earned monies!

Comment: That's indeed correct. Didn't quite occur to me to look for the tabs on the top. Got too caught up and frustrated with looking for the option on the default tab.